# Dual Booting Problems

Tags: dual-boot

Okay so i decided earlier today to try out ubuntu, i didnt want to get rid of windows as i still have games i want to play so i decided to dual boot. I made a LiveCD from a thumb drive and instaleed ubuntu on my harddrive. I had shrunk the windows partition to make space for ubuntu. I finished installing ubuntu and it works beautifully and i really like it. When i tried a while ago to start up windows 7 through the GRUB, it says the following BOOTMCR image is corrupt. The system cannot boot. I honestly have no idea what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair/) I think this can solve the problem.

Log in into Ubuntu and Install Boot Repair and hopefully running that should fix the problem.